# Vagrant scotch box not working

Tags: php, apache, vagrant, vagrantfile

I installed vagrant 2.0 with Virtualbox on a Windows 7.
I followed the https://box.scotch.io/ guide but and I cannot access the webserver at http://192.168.33.10:8080

I entered the box via ssh and says that apache2 is not installed and neither is php. They should be, right?

My VagrantFile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "scotch/box"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
  config.vm.hostname = "scotchbox"
  config.vm.synced_folder ".","/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]
  config.ssh.username = "vagrant"
  config.ssh.password = "vagrant"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you do not need forward_port if you use a private network, when you have a static ip, you will reach the server directly using the IP; or you could with the forward port, but certainly not a mix of your VM static IP and the forwarding port to your host machine; with your setup either http://192.168.33.10 or http://127.0.0.1:8080 would work, but I'd just recommend to remove the forward port and just use the VM IP
2. you dont need `config.ssh` parameters, just login with the ssh key.